# How to reduce by two keys in spark streaming?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I have the following type of data coming from a Kafka Consumer

```
(u'0:l1', ({u'partyField': u'0:n5m, u'attr1': u'ok'})
(u'0:l1', ({u'partyField': u'0:n8m, u'attr1': u'ok'})
(u'0:l1', ({u'partyField': u'0:n8m, u'attr1': u'ok'})
```

I'd like to perform a `reduceByKey` operation on this. Currently, I get the following output

```
(u'0:l1', {u'partyField': u'0:n5m, u'attr1': u'ok'}, 
{u'partyField': u'0:n8m, u'attr1': u'ok'}, 
{u'partyField': u'0:n8m, u'attr1': u'ok'})
```

But I'd like to have some kind of key combination as I'd like to group by one more parameter which is part of the value i.e. `partyField`

I'm looking get a grouping similar to this i.e. grouped by the key and also `partyField`

```
(u'0:l1', ({u'partyField': u'0:n5m, u'attr1': u'ok'})

(u'0:l1', {u'partyField': u'0:n8m, u'attr1': u'ok'},
u'0:l1', {u'partyField': u'0:n8m, u'attr1': u'ok'})
```

How can I perform this operation in spark?

Comment: Why not keep keys as existing keys and partyField?

Comment: @mad_ didn't really get you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form the key based on the `partyField` of each record and apply `reduceByKey` and extract the values from the `reduced_rdd`.

For example:

```
>>> in_rdd = sc.parallelize(a)
[('0:l1', {'partyField': '0:n5m', 'attr1': 'ok'}),
 ('0:l1', {'partyField': '0:n8m', 'attr1': 'ok'}),
 ('0:l1', {'partyField': '0:n8m', 'attr1': 'ok'})]
>>> key_rdd = in_rdd.map(lambda x : (x[1]['partyField'],x))
>>> reduced_rdd = key_rdd.reduceByKey(lambda acc, curr: acc + curr)
>>> final_rdd = reduced_rdd.map(lambda x: x[1])
>>> final_rdd.collect()
[('0:l1',{'partyField': '0:n8m', 'attr1': 'ok'}, 
  '0:l1',{'partyField': '0:n8m', 'attr1': 'ok'}),

 ('0:l1',{'partyField': '0:n5m', 'attr1': 'ok'})]
```

Hope this helps!